# How to assign an ID to identify duplicate array elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary, duplicates

I have a multi-dimensional array which contains a string and another array for each element.

```
duplicates = 
[["link_A", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],    
 ["link_B", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],    # Same coordinates as previous line
 ["link_C", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],    # Same coordinates as previous line
 ["link_D", [247471, 671767, 247567, 671846]],
 ["link_E", [247471, 671767, 247567, 671846]],    # Same coordinates as previous line
 ["link_F", [247567, 671846, 247775, 671680]],
 ["link_G", [247567, 671846, 247775, 671680]]]    # Same coordinates as previous line
```

I have my data in a format that I want in order to go through the "duplicates" array using "each" and export the data to .csv.

The only thing I want at this point is for an assigned ID/number for every duplicate that has the same coordinates. Happy to have it as an element in the array, such as:

**Desired Output:**

```
duplicates = 
[["1", "link_A", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],    
 ["1", "link_B", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],    # Same coordinates as previous line
 ["1", "link_C", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],    # Same coordinates as previous line
 ["2", "link_D", [247471, 671767, 247567, 671846]],
 ["2", "link_E", [247471, 671767, 247567, 671846]],    # Same coordinates as previous line
 ["3", "link_F", [247567, 671846, 247775, 671680]],
 ["3", "link_G", [247567, 671846, 247775, 671680]]]    # Same coordinates as previous line
```

What's the best way of going about this?

Many thanks.

**Edit:**

Thank you for the responses. The current 3 answers (from 1. Siim Liiser, 2. Cary Swoveland and 3. iGian) all work well for me with slight variation (I believe - correct me if I'm wrong!):

1. Doesn't mutate "duplicates" // Doesn't assume in order
2. Doesn't mutate "duplicates" // Assumes duplicates in order
3. Mutates "duplicates" // Doesn't assume in order

I didn't mention it in the question but I was okay with duplicates itself being mutated. I had previously used "group_by" (little bit more info below) to create duplicates so the order shouldn't really matter either. Thanks again.

---

Original array (seen as 'segment_store' below) at very start holds the link name (e.g. "link_A") and an array of coords (two XY coords) - these represent link segments. As I was looking to find duplicates, I used:

```
duplicates = segment_store.group_by{|i| i[1]}.select{|k,v| v.length > 1}.values.flatten(1)
```

to get duplicates as seen in original question (pre-edit).

Comment: Suppose the arrays associated with `"link_F"` and `"link_G"` were the same as the array associated with `"link_A"`. The comments in your code, "Same coordinates as previous line" suggest that the last two lines of the desired array would continue to begin `["3", "link_F",` and `["3", "link_G",`; only the arrays would differ. But then you say you want "an assigned ID/number for every duplicate that has the same coordinates". That would suggest the elements in the desired array for `"link_F"` and `"link_G"` would begin with `"1"` rather than `"3"`. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Hi Cary, I'm not quite certain what you mean here - I've added a little more info about how "duplicates" is created that should (hopefully) already be in order, if that changes things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using an infinite enumerator to hold the ids and a hash to cache the first occurrence of an array.

```
enum = 1.step
duplicates.each_with_object({}).map do |(string, array), cache|
  [cache[array] ||= enum.next, string, array]
end
```

Call `.to_s` on the first element to get an identical result to yours.

On average should be O(n) time with O(n) extra space.

Does not assume duplicates being consecutive. If they are always consecutive as in your example, then a different algorithm could easily be more space efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have this dataset (I used a Symbol instead of the array of coordinates for simplicity), note the last (H) element having the same coordinates as the first:

```
duplicates = 
  [["link_A", :coords_a],    
   ["link_B", :coords_a],
   ["link_C", :coords_a],
   ["link_D", :coords_d],
   ["link_E", :coords_d],
   ["link_F", :coords_f],
   ["link_G", :coords_f],
   ["link_H", :coords_a]]
```

Consider to use the [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method to get an output like this:

```
duplicates.group_by(&:last)

#   {:coords_a=>[["link_A", :coords_a], ["link_B", :coords_a], ["link_C", :coords_a], ["link_H", :coords_a]],
#    :coords_d=>[["link_D", :coords_d], ["link_E", :coords_d]], 
#    :coords_f=>[["link_F", :coords_f], ["link_G", :coords_f]]}
```

---

Then, use the values of the hash (`duplicates.group_by(&:last).values`), which are groups and map them adding the index, using [Enumerable#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).

The final result is the one liner:

```
duplicates.group_by(&:last).values
          .flat_map.with_index(1) { |val, id| val.map { |e| e.unshift id } }

#   [[1, "link_A", :coords_a], [1, "link_B", :coords_a], [1, "link_C", :coords_a], [1, "link_H", :coords_a],
#    [2, "link_D", :coords_d], [2, "link_E", :coords_d],
#    [3, "link_F", :coords_f], [3, "link_G", :coords_f]]
```

---

If you could mutate the `duplicate` array, you could also do something similar but using `Enumerable#each`, instead of `Enumerable#flat_map`:

```
duplicates.group_by(&:last).values
          .each.with_index(1) { |val, id| val.map { |e| e.unshift id } }
duplicates

# [[1, "link_A", :coords_a],
#  [1, "link_B", :coords_a],
#  [1, "link_C", :coords_a],
#  [2, "link_D", :coords_d],
#  [2, "link_E", :coords_d],
#  [3, "link_F", :coords_f],
#  [3, "link_G", :coords_f],
#  [1, "link_H", :coords_a]]
```

---

Maybe you want to convert the index to String.

Comment: Consider `duplicates.chunk(&:last).flat_map.with_index(1) { |(_,val), id| val.map { |e| [id, *e] } }`. Note that `e.unshift id` mutates `duplicates`.

Comment: Maybe not. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for the precious hints as usual. I upgraded my answer.

Comment: The code following "The final result is the one liner:" also mutates `duplicates`, the culprit being `e.unshift id`. Also, I'm not sure it's helpful to give a solution that mutates `duplicates` since the OP has not asked for that.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with one pass through `duplicates`:

```
duplicates.each_with_object([]) do |(link,a),arr|
  arr <<
    if arr.empty?
      ['1', link, a]
    else
      i, _, b = arr.last 
      [a == b ? i : (i.to_i+1).to_s, link, a]
    end
end
  #=> [["1", "link_A", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],
  #    ["1", "link_B", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],
  #    ["1", "link_C", [247936, 672212, 248156, 671720]],
  #    ["2", "link_D", [247471, 671767, 247567, 671846]],
  #    ["2", "link_E", [247471, 671767, 247567, 671846]],
  #    ["3", "link_F", [247567, 671846, 247775, 671680]],
  #    ["3", "link_G", [247567, 671846, 247775, 671680]]]
```

One could alternatively write:

```
duplicates.
  drop(1).each_with_object([["1",*duplicates.first]]) do |(link,a),arr|
  i, _, b = arr.last 
  arr << [a == b ? i : (i.to_i+1).to_s, link, a]
end
```